# Change comment-char in Notepad++ to "|"

Tags: comments, notepad++

How do I change `#` to `|` as a comment sign in Notepad++?

In which language syntax comments are `|`?

Comment: In which cases do want to change `#` to `|`? Show some sample text.

Comment: When I press ctrl+q it will appear #. I want that it will appear |.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language have `|` as comments sign.

You have to define your own language rules. You can choose the comments sign in the file langs.model.xml (in the Notepad++ installation directory), see the attribut `commentLine=` for each language.

Comment: It's not working. When I defined my own language rules with name "4GL" it didn't appear in the file langs.model.xml. When I changed attribut commentLine= in selected lannguage, then it didn't change - for example I selected KIX language and in langs.model.xml changed:
**<Language name="kix" ext="kix" commentLine="#" commentStart="" commentEnd="">**
to:
**<Language name="kix" ext="kix" commentLine="|" commentStart="" commentEnd="">**
...but it didn't change anything...
When I click ctrl+q it still appears **#**

Comment: @Lukasz: You may have more answer if you ask the developpers: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 0):

In SynWrite app you can change comment-char for "Text files" lexer: call "Options - Customize lexer" dialog, fill field "Line comment string" with "|".
Now command "Comment lines" adds "|".

Comment: I asked question about Notepad++, not about SynWrite.